# Accessing nested JSON [String: Any] object and appending to it

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

Using swift, I am attempting to access the "locations" object within the "locationConstraint" part of a JSON that looks like this:

```
        let jsonObj : [String: Any] =
            [
                "attendees": [
                    [
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": [
                            "name": nameOfRoom,
                            "address": roomEmailAddress
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "locationConstraint": [
                    "isRequired": "true",
                    "suggestLocation": "false",
                    "locations": [
                        [
                            "displayName": "First Floor Test Meeting Room 1",
                            "locationEmailAddress": "FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@onmicrosoft.com"
                        ],
                        [
                            "displayName": "Ground Floor Test Meeting Room 1",
                            "locationEmailAddress": "GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@onmicrosoft.com"
                        ]
                        //and the rest of the rooms below this.. 
                    ]
                ],
                "meetingDuration": durationOfMeeting,
        ]
```

I am attempting to add items to the locations from outside this method (to prevent repetitive code, as location list could be large) - but I am having problems replacing back into this part of the json..

My method to do this:

```
static func setupJsonObjectForFindMeetingTimeAllRoomsTest(nameOfRoom: String, roomEmailAddress: String, dateStartString: String, dateEndString: String, durationOfMeeting: String, locations: [String]) -> [String: Any] {
    let jsonObj : [String: Any] =
        [
            "attendees": [
                [
                    "type": "required",
                    "emailAddress": [
                        "name": nameOfRoom,
                        "address": roomEmailAddress
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "meetingDuration": durationOfMeeting
    ]

    let jsonObject = addLocationsToExistingJson(locations:locations, jsonObj: jsonObj)
    return jsonObject
}
```

and my method to add locations to the existing json object:

```
static func addLocationsToExistingJson(locations: [String], jsonObj: [String: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
    var  data: [String: Any] = jsonObj

    let locConstraintObj = [
            "isRequired": "true",
            "suggestLocation": "false",
            "locations" : []

        ] as [String : Any]

    //try access locationConstraint part of json
    data["locationConstraint"] = locConstraintObj

    for i in stride(from: 0, to: locations.count, by: 1) {
        let item: [String: Any] =  [
            "displayName": locations[i],
            "locationEmailAddress": locations[i]
        ]

        // get existing items, or create new array if doesn't exist
        //this line below wrong? I need to access data["locationConstraint]["locations"]
        //but an error occurs when i change to the above.. .how do i access it?
        var existingItems = data["locations"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[String: Any]]()

        // append the item
        existingItems.append(item)

        // replace back into `data`
       data["locations"] = existingItems
    }
    return data
}
```

So ultimately, my final json object that works should look like this:

> ["meetingDuration": "PT60M", "returnSuggestionReasons": "true",
>   "attendees": [["emailAddress": ["address":
>   "TestUser6@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com", "name": "N"], "type":
>   "required"]], "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100",
>   "locationConstraint": ["locations": [["displayName": "First Floor Test
>   Meeting Room 1", "locationEmailAddress":
>   "FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"], ["displayName":
>   "Ground Floor Test Meeting Room 1", "locationEmailAddress":
>   "GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"]],
>   "suggestLocation": "false", "isRequired": "true"], "timeConstraint":
>   ["activityDomain": "unrestricted", "timeslots": [["start":
>   ["dateTime": "2019-02-07 14:30:00", "timeZone": "UTC"], "end":
>   ["dateTime": "2019-02-07 15:30:00", "timeZone": "UTC"]]]],
>   "isOrganizerOptional": "true"]

Where as it looks like this:

> ["timeConstraint": ["activityDomain": "unrestricted", "timeslots":
>   [["start": ["dateTime": "2019-02-08 08:30:00", "timeZone": "UTC"],
>   "end": ["dateTime": "2019-02-08 09:30:00", "timeZone": "UTC"]]]],
>   "locationConstraint": ["suggestLocation": "false", "locations": [],
>   "isRequired": "true"], "attendees": [["emailAddress": ["address":
>   "TestUser6@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com", "name": "N"], "type":
>   "required"]], "returnSuggestionReasons": "true",
>   "isOrganizerOptional": "true", "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100",
>   "locations": [["locationEmailAddress":
>   "FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com", "displayName":
>   "FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"],
>   ["locationEmailAddress":
>   "GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com", "displayName":
>   "GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"]],
>   "meetingDuration": "PT60M"]

Where the locations object is being added outside the locationConstraint part of the JSON.. I know I need to be accessing the locationConstraint part of my json like this:     `var existingItems = data["locationConstraint"]!["locations"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[String: Any]]()` but this returns an error:

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

This is my first time working with JSONs and trying to manipulate them in swift.. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: I think you should be following [Apple's advice](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) and creating a Model Object from your JSON which you will find easier to manipulate. Using generic collection classes to represent a DOM will always be difficult to use, so it's worth the effort to create domain-specific classes.

Comment: I would suggest you not to create the array of locationConstraint and then before sending the data append the other parameters. Also, you need to type cast the Any to proper formats like array or dictionary.

Comment: @Sachin Vas can you show me what you mean?

Comment: if let locations = data["locationConstraint]["locations"] as? [[String: Any]] { `YOUR_CODE_HERE` }

Comment: @Sachin Vas it gives me the errors: Chain the optional using '?' to access member 'subscript' only for non-'nil' base values 
and 
Value of optional type 'Any?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type 'Any'

Then when I change it to if let locations = data["locationConstraint"]?["locations"] as? [[String: Any]] {
           
        }

the error is : Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: Sorry, Forgot that, if let locations = (data["locationConstraint] as? [String:Any])?["locations"] as? [[String: Any]] { `YOUR_CODE_HERE` }. This should solve it.

Comment: @Sachin Vas thank you, that worked!

Comment: Instead of having that structure, I would create a method just for each dictionary (locationConstraints) or an array of dictionaries(locations). This would follow the Single Responsibility rule and people can understand your code more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution by using model objects and Codable

as trojanfoe proposed, you should use model objects and manipulate them directly.

```
import Foundation

struct Meeting: Codable {
    var attendees: [Attendee]
    var locationConstraint: LocationConstraint
    var meetingDuration: Int
}

struct Attendee: Codable {
    var type: Type
    var emailAddress: EmailAdress

    enum `Type`: String, Codable {
        case required
    }
}

struct LocationConstraint: Codable {
    var isRequired: Bool
    var suggestLocation: Bool
    var locations: [Location]
}

struct EmailAdress: Codable {
    var name: String
    var address: String
}

struct Location: Codable {
    var displayName: String
    var locationEmailAddress: String
}
```

At first we take your dictionary...

```
let jsonDict: [String: Any] =
    [
        "attendees": [
            [
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": [
                    "name": "specificName",
                    "address": "specificAdress"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "locationConstraint": [
            "isRequired": true,
            "suggestLocation": false,
            "locations": [
                [
                    "displayName": "First Floor Test Meeting Room 1",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@onmicrosoft.com"
                ],
                [
                    "displayName": "Ground Floor Test Meeting Room 1",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@onmicrosoft.com"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "meetingDuration": 1800,
]
```

... and serialize it.

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: .prettyPrinted)
print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
```

We then decode it into our meeting model.

```
var meeting = try JSONDecoder().decode(Meeting.self, from: jsonData)
```

We initialize a new location and append it to our meeting.locationConstraints.locations array.

```
let newLocation = Location(displayName: "newDisplayName", locationEmailAddress: "newLocationEmailAdress")
meeting.locationConstraint.locations.append(newLocation)
```

And finally reencode our model object again.

```
let updatedJsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(meeting)
print(String(data: updatedJsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it!